# T -SQL for select from update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

```
Customer: Id, FirstName, LastName, Email
CommunityUser: Id, FirstName, LastName, Email , CustomerId
BlogComment: Id, CustomerId, Text
```

How to use T-SQL to set for each `BlogComment.CustomerId` to the corresponding `CommunityUser.Id` 
I tried :

```
For select * from  BlogComment bc
update bc set CustomerId = (select cu.Id from CommunityUser cu Where cu.CustomerId = bc.CustomerId)
```

but it is not valid syntax

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do here but even if this was valid syntax the logic is flawed. You are trying to update BlogComment and changing the CustomerID but you are also using that as a join condition. Here is a great place to start for your question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

Simple update with joining CommunityUser will help

```
Update B
set b.Customerid = cu.id
from BlogComment b inner join CommunityUser cu
on b.Costumerid = cu.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update BlogComment bc
set CustomerId = (select Id from CommunityUser cu Where cu.CustomerId = bc.CustomerId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
UPDATE bc 
SET bc.CustomerId = cu.Id 
FROM CommunityUser cu INNER JOIN BlogComment bc 
ON cu.CustomerId = bc.CustomerId
```